# Populating the Mat table(and perform Sorting & Filtering) using JSON Response

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, mat-table

I'm new to Angular 7 and working on the Angular Mat table to display the response from the backend server and perform sorting, filtering and pagination on the data.

Pagination is working as expected but sorting and filtering are not working properly. I have also imported all the required modules.
Can someone help me with this?

Joblist.component.ts

```
import { Component ,ViewChild, OnInit ,AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableDataSource,MatPaginator,MatSort,Sort} from '@angular/material';
import { BackupService } from '../backup.service';

export interface jobs{
  status : string

}

@Component({
    templateUrl :'joblist.component.html',
    styleUrls :['joblist.component.css']
})

export class JoblistComponent  implements OnInit,AfterViewInit{
  public displayedColumns = ['status'];
  public dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<jobs>();


  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  constructor(private backupService: BackupService) { }

    ngOnInit()
    {
       this.getAllJobs(); 
    }

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    }

    public doFilter = (value: string) => {
      this.dataSource.filter = value.trim().toLocaleLowerCase();
    }

    getAllJobs() {
      this.backupService.getJobs(
        response => {
          console.log("response =>"+response);    
          this.dataSource.data = response.jobs as jobs[];
          console.log("datasource =>"+this.dataSource);
        },
        error => {
          console.log("error=>", error);
        });
    }
```

joblist.component.html

```
<div fxLayout fxLayoutAlign="center center">
  <mat-form-field fxFlex="40%">
    <input matInput type="text" (keyup)="doFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20,50,100]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort >
  <ng-container matColumnDef="status">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Status</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.jobSummary.status}} </td>
  </ng-container>
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Response from Backend server

```
{
    "jobs": [
        {
            "jobSummary": {
                "status": "full"
            }
        },
        {
            "jobSummary": {
                "status": "completed"
            }
        },
        {
            "jobSummary": {
                "status": "partial"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Searching and Sorting are not working on the response.

Comment: Try setting the paginator and the sort after you have set the data for the dataSource.
getAllJobs() {
      this.backupService.getJobs(
        response => {
          console.log("response =>"+response);    
          this.dataSource.data = response.jobs as jobs[];
          this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
          this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
          console.log("datasource =>"+this.dataSource);
        },
        error => {
          console.log("error=>", error);
        });
    }

Comment: I tried setting the paginator and sort after the datasource. It doesnt work.

Comment: the same issue I am also facing ```matTable``` directly cannot sort JSON inside JSON

Answer (score 1):

I think it may be a data source initialization issue.

```js
import { Component ,ViewChild ,AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableDataSource,MatPaginator,MatSort,Sort} from '@angular/material';
import { BackupService } from '../backup.service';

export interface jobs{
  status : string

}

@Component({
    templateUrl :'joblist.component.html',
    styleUrls :['joblist.component.css']
})

export class JoblistComponent  implements AfterViewInit{
  public displayedColumns = ['status'];
  public dataSource: MatTableDataSource;


  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  constructor(private backupService: BackupService) { }

    onTableDataReceived(data: any[]) {
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data);
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    }

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
      this.getAllJobs(); 
    }

    public doFilter = (value: string) => {
      this.dataSource.filter = value.trim().toLocaleLowerCase();
    }

    getAllJobs() {
      this.backupService.getJobs(
        response => {
          console.log("response =>"+response);    
          const data = response.jobs as jobs[];
          this.onTableDataReceived(data);
        },
        error => {
          console.log("error=>", error);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Searching and sorting is working for this reponse : {
   "jobs": [
        {
            "status": "full"
        },
        {
            "status": "partial"
        },
        {
            "status": "completed"
        }
    ]
}

Answer (score 0):

Material table by default sorts on ID column. If you want to retain the back-end service ordering set index to the list items and then use this as sort column. This retains the order of back-end service.

In my case i had to sort on value of a field not asc/desc and assign priority in back-end and then show in UI.

```
    Long[] idx = { 0L };
    list.forEach(a->a.setOrderId(idx[0]++));
  return list;
```

Hope this helps !!

PS: Angular 7 is the version.